# Cordova error building after adding plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-sdk-tools, phonegap-cli

Hello I'm using latest version of Cordova 6.1.0 and Android SDK Tools.

when I add any admob plugins. the following error message returned after using build command.

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'

how can I fix this?

BTW please don't send workarounds for Android Studio. I just need to be able to build APK files via cordova and I don't use Android Studio.

Full error details as following:

> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_71
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   >     Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:+.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
>   >          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
>   >      Required by:
>   >          :android:unspecified
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 11.78 secs
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>     /s,/c,"C:\nm\tests\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>     C:\nm\tests\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>     -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: try run this command and check - **android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"**

Comment: Thanx I tried it, but still getting the same error message

Comment: did u tried removing the android platform and adding it again and build. It works for me though. Also could you send the stacktrace of error for better clarity

Comment: i tried this too. I removed android platform and the plugin which was causing the issue and then added both again.

could you inform me how to print or export stacktrace. can I do this via  Cordova command prompt?

Comment: you will get the error trace in the command prompt itself when trying to do 'cordova build android' Try posting the complete trace so that it will be helpful for others to answer

Comment: looks like its an issue with admob plugin.. Check this link - https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/issues/169 Hope it helps

Comment: if it was helpful, you can upvote the comment so that it will be helpful for others to track down the fix who are facing similar issues. Thanks in advance.